# WinUI3 C++ Frame overlapping

Tags: windows, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm trying to add logic to navigate among pages. I use the following code when the MainWindow is initialized:

```
MainFrame().Navigate(winrt::xaml_typename<Page1>());
```

The main window frame looks like this:

```
<Grid
    Background="#001C13">
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" />
</Grid>
```

In the FirstPage there is a button that does

```
MainFrame().Navigate(winrt::xaml_typename<Page2>());
```

The result when trying to go to Page2 is that the elements are overlapped instead of the first page dissapearing.
What could be the problem?

Comment: I do, but that is not the correct answer, I was able to fix that by following an example from here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-dev-docs/tree/docs

Answer (score 0):

To enable navigation between pages, add a `Frame` as the root element of `MainWindow`. You can do that in the `Application.OnLaunched` method override in the `App.xaml` code-behind file.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        m_window = new MainWindow();

        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        Frame MainFrame = new Frame();
        //MainFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
        // Navigate to the first page, configuring the new page
        // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
        MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments);

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        m_window.Content = MainFrame;
        // Ensure the MainWindow is active
        m_window.Activate();
    }
```

For more details, you could refer to the Doc: [Implement navigation between two pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages?tabs=wasdk)